# Regular Expression for line starting with a number followed by tab

Tags: regex

I have a really simple question.  I figured out that the regular expression for a line that starts with a number is ^(\s+)?\d+

I want a regular expression for lines that starts with a number, followed by a tab.  Naturally I assumed that ^(\s+)?\d+\t would do the job.  Unfortunately it is not working.  I would appreciate if somebody could point out the error in my expression.

Regards,
SS

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: ^(\s+)? can be replaced with ^\s*

Comment: @Denziloe Not if he was interested in capturing those spaces :-)

Comment: @horcrux I have a feeling he would know about the Kleene star if he know about capturing groups. ; )

Comment: Maybe `^[ \t]*\d+\t`

Comment: *Unfortunately it is not working* => you should explain a bit more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(^|(?<=\n))\d+\t
```

breakin' it down:

`^` is the start of the string.

`(?<=\n)` is a positive lookbehind on `\n`.

so either you match the start of the string, or you match something following a new line.

and what you're matching after either of those conditions is `\d+\t`, which means one or more digits followed by a tab.